# Apc extension not working on php 5.3.3

Tags: php, apc, wampserver, apachebench, opcode-cache

opcode caching talk.I have WAMP server 2.1 running PHP 5.3.3.I'm using apache benchmark to test the improvement APC adds when applied to my php scripts.

```
ab -n 10 -c 5 http://localhost/mysite/index/index/
```

I installed [APC 3.1.6 for PHP 5.3 vc6](http://dev.freshsite.pl/download.html) with the following settings in php.ini:

```
extension= c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\ext\php_apc_316_php53_vc6.dll
apc.enabled=1
apc.stat=0
apc.optimization=9
apc.shm_size=30
apc.max_file_size=2
```

this is what I get:

[image]

I need to comment out the extension line to have this test run properly
Why?

[here](http://imageshack.us/f/707/apcsettings.jpg/) my phpinfo() Apc settings

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `apc.max_file_size = 2M`. Otherwise max filesize would be 2 bytes.